# Сделать образ системного диска

Tags: windows, windows-10, образ

Как в Windows 10 из самой системы сделать образ системного диска?
Должна быть возможность монтировать этот образ на другом компе.

Возможности загрузить другую систему с флешки/диска нет.

Comment: а вам обязательно из системы?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, откуда ещё, если ничего другого я загрузить не могу?

Comment: я честно говоря все-равно не очень понимаю что у вас происходит, вы рассматривали вариант сделать образ загрузившись из dos?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, из биоса запрещена загрузка с флешек, на биосе пароль.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, можно recovery-mode винды загрузить, но я не знаю, чем это поможет.

Comment: сейчас опубликую ответ, то как я делал у себя на ноуте, когда была ваша ситуация

Comment: А винт выкрутить нельзя?

Comment: @donRumata, это слишком варварский метод)

Comment: Это рабочий на 100% метод.

Comment: Есть такая утилитка - [disk2vhd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/disk2vhd) от Sysinternals. С её помощью я снимал образ диска с win7 прямо в ней же работающей.

Comment: @woesss, а образ получается нормальный, не битый? Обязательно попробую.

Comment: Да, нормальный - монтировать, ковыряться в файлах можно. Но если хотите с него загружать систему, то без бубна не обойтись.

Comment: @woesss, загружаться не планирую, вроде бы всё получилось. Флажок про vhdx оставил, про теневую копию - снял. Ответ напишешь?

Comment: @woesss, хотя стоп...

Comment: @woesss, с правами доступа что-то странное получилось...

Comment: Ничего странного - другая система, другой юзер - права надо править. Это ж NTFS, не флешка с FATом. Тут хоть чем образ снимай, хоть физический диск перекидывай, хоть с другой системы загрузись на этой же машине - те же грабли будут.

Comment: @woesss, они как-то странно выставлены... По идее, во всей папке должны быть одинаковыми, но нет - часть файлов видно, часть нет. Но если смотреть от админа, то всё на месте.

Answer (score 0):

С учетом того что у вас нету доступа к загрузке из доса вам остается только делать образ штатными способами и надеяться что все что вам нужно будет находится в образе. Честно говоря у меня была только один раз подобная ситуация, а на данный момент я использую Acronis для создания и развертывания образов. Вам нужно зайти в панель задач и перейти в раздел который показан на рисунке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дальше в этой пункте вам нужно выбрать подпункт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и дальше переходите сюда:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 вроде как все, но здесь будут копироваться только те файлы которые необходимы для работы программ, ваши файлы не будут скопированы.

Если все-таки вам нужно самому решать что и как копировать вам нужно перейти в раздел `Настроить параметры резервного копирования`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

здесь вы сможете выбрать где будет хранится ваша копия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ну и дальше выбираете что и как вы хотите сохранить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот [ссылка](http://pronetblog.by/sozdanie-obraza-sistemy-windows-10.html#a1) на первоисточник. Надеюсь я помог в решении вашей проблемы, но вообще штатные средства ОС не дают столько свободы, как например Acronis поэтому очень сложно будет достичь подобного результата.

Comment: Я так попробовал (правда, не настраивал), что-то у меня из создавшегося бэкапа ничего достать не получилось. Сам бэкап не монтируется, при извлечении img-файла 7Zip'ом пишется ошибка про неожиданный конец архива и он тоже не монтируется.